# How to use regex expression to split str based off multiple characters in expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, split, delimiter

Sorry if the wording is bad. So I'm trying to find out how to pass in a string match of multiple characters long into my dynamic regex expression.

The regex in my else statement works with 1 character being passed in so I'm trying to do the same thing except with multiple characters being passed in the first if statement.

```
const delimiter = str.slice(0, str.indexOf('\n'));
  const strLength = delimiter.length;
  if (delimiter[0] === '[' && delimiter.charAt(strLength - 1) === ']') {
    const customDelimiter = delimiter.slice(delimiter.indexOf(delimiter[1]), delimiter.indexOf(delimiter.charAt(strLength - 1)));
    console.log(customDelimiter) // => '***'
    const regex = new RegExp(`,|\\n|\\${customDelimiter}`,'g');
    return strArr = str.split(regex).filter(Boolean);
  } else {
    const firstChar = str.slice(0, 1); // => '*'
    const regex = new RegExp(`,|\\n|\\${firstChar}`,'g');
    return strArr = str.split(regex).filter(Boolean);
  }
```

So for example I want this string:
'[***]\n11***22***33' to equal 66 b/c it should split it into an array of [11, 22, 33] using the '***' delimiter. I get an error message saying: "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /,|\n|***/: Nothing to repeat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `*` as delimeter in your regex, it becomes `,|\\n|\\|\*`, which is the correct regex.
It matches ',' or '\n' or a '*' character.
For your string, it matches [`***`]`\n`11`***`22`***`33.

But when you use `***` as a delimiter in your regex, it becomes `,|\\n|\\|\***`, which is incorrect. Here it gets two unescaped `*` at the end. `*` in regex means 0 or more of the preceding pattern. You cannot have two of them together.

This is a special case because `*` has a special meaning in regex.
If you would have used any non-regex character, it would work.

A simpler solution would be to use javascript split function to easily get the desired result.
You could first split the string using `\n`.

```
let splitStr = str.split('\n');
// This would return ["[***]", "11***22***33"]
```

and then split the 1st index of the splitStr using the delimeter.

```
splitStr[1].split('***');
// splitStr[1].split(customDelimiter)
// This would return ["11", "22", "33"]
```

Using this you wouldn't need to use if or else statement to separate out single character delimiter and multiple character delimiter.

Comment: ohhh thats a good solution! Thank you! I also did figure it out by using format `(delimiter){3}` into my regex expression.
So going from: new RegExp(`,|\\n|\\${customDelimiter}`,'g');
To: new RegExp(`,|\\n|\\${customCharacter}{${customDelimiterLength}}`,'g');
That worked for me!

Comment: Your regex solution would definitely work for `***`. But using `customDelimiterLength` will not work if you have delimiter with different characters like `**/`.

Comment: thats a great point! I may have to go with your solution because that is case I will have to worry about later on. Thank you!